# Why javascrpt does not select the button?

Tags: javascript, django

I am creating with javascript that when I select the like button it prints Hi.
I don't understand why when inspecting it is not selecting the button.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Can it be that I do not get the javascript url?

index.hmtl

```
<script src="{% static 'network/index.js' %}"></script>
```

```
<form method="post">{%csrf_token%}
        <button onclick="darLike()">Like</button>
        <a id="resultado"></a>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16 " height="16 " fill="currentColor " class="bi bi-heart " viewBox="0 0 16 16 ">
            <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333
            4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z "/>
        </svg>
    </form>
```

index.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => function darLike() {
        const contenido = document.querySelector('#resultado')
        fetch(`like/${post.id}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
                }
            })
            // Put response into json form
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                contenido.innerHTML = "Hi"
            })
            // Catch any errors and log them to the console
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error:', error);
            });
    });
    // Prevent default submission
    return false;
})
```

Comment: why are you adding `click` listener to the `document`?

Comment: I don't know if this is the only problem (it's not clear what the `post` variable is as I don't see it declared in your file) - but your click listener is a function that simply returns a function, and doesn't do anything. I assume that isn't what you meant, so replace `() => function darlike() {...}` with just `function darlike() {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You have added `click` listener to whole document, which is not required. Instead you want `click` event only on the `button`, which is already added in your `html` code.

In the below code

```
document.addEventListener('click', () => function darLike() {..}))
```

Your callback function is returning `another function` with name `darLike` and is not executing any code.

When you use the `onclick` the function needs to be globally available.

Instead you can attach `click` event to the button using `addEventListener`.

The `DOMContentLoaded` is available on `window` object and not `document`. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

```
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
  <button>Like </button> // Removed onclick
      ...
</form>

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', darLike);

  function darLike() {
    const contenido = document.querySelector('#resultado')
    fetch(`like/${post.id}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
      }
    })
    ...
  }
});
```